# Is there a thread-safe TQueue in Delphi 2007?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Is there a thread-safe TQueue in Delphi 2007?
or the one defined in unit Contnrs is the thread-safe ?

Comment: AFAICT, D2007 does not have a thread-safe TQueue. You'll have to make use a critical section when accessing it in order to handle thread safety issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Delphi 2007 does not have a thread-safe `TQueue`. You'll need to make use of a critical section when accessing it in order to use it with multiple threads. The one in `Contnrs` is not thread-safe.

Comment: You need a bit more than a lock. You also need a condition variable so that consumers can wait until there is something to consume.